# Click div, fade in div, click div OR outside div to fade out div

Tags: jquery, html, click, fade

So I have a little code, that I know works, that makes it so when you press on a div it opens a second div (which is set to display: none in css). You then click on the same div that you click to open the second div to close it (fade out).

However, I want to be able to make it so you can click *OUTSIDE* and it would fade out. I've tried numerous of codes, yet I cannot get it working. Please help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dashbox").click(function() {
        $("#dashboardbox").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a click event to the document that, if the box is not already invisible, checks that it did not get triggered by clicking #dashboardbox or #dashbox (would trigger toggle twice) or any of their children. If all is well it will then fade out the box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        // Skip if already hidden
        if(!$('#dashboardbox').is(":visible"))
            return;

        // Skip if clicked dashbox or its children
        if ($(event.target).closest('#dashbox').length)
            return;

        // Skip if clicked dashboardbox or its children
        if ($(event.target).closest('#dashboardbox').length)
            return;

        // Fade out
        $("#dashboardbox").fadeOut();
    });

    $("#dashbox").click(function(e) {
        $("#dashboardbox").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5h1ajLft/).

Comment: Oh, and please mark my answer as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped solve your problem. That would [build reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) on this site for both you and me :) And good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by attaching an additional handler that will `fadeOut` the div whether or not it is visible

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
        if(e.target.id != "dashbox"){
            $("#dashboardbox").fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cg8ae0kn/9/)